# Finding four square roots of $\small\begin{bmatrix}3 & -4\\4 & 3\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

This question is about finding the 4(!!) square roots of a 2 by 2 matrix. The method I use is through Diagonalization (or actually doing the "opposite"). I have no problem finding the four roots of a 2 by 2 matrix that has real eigenvalues (and thus real eigen vectors). Heck, I found 8 roots of a 3 by 3 matrix that has real eigen values. The problem I am running into is if the to be square rooted matrix has complex eigenvalues. In my view, the method should work the same, but somehow the algebra is letting me down. Example: Find the four square roots of
$ \begin{bmatrix}3 & -4\\4 & 3\end{bmatrix}$. Note, I found this matrix by squaring $ \begin{bmatrix}2 & -1\\1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$, so obviously this is one root as well as taking opposite of its entries. So here is my work: The characteristic equation of $ \begin{bmatrix}3 & -4\\4 & 3\end{bmatrix}$ is $(3-\lambda)^2+16=0$ from which we find $\lambda=3+4i$ and $\lambda=3-4i$. An eigenvector for $\lambda=3+4i$ is $ \begin{bmatrix}1 \\-i  \end{bmatrix}$ and an eigenvector for $\lambda=3-4i$ is $ \begin{bmatrix}1 \\i  \end{bmatrix}$. So the given matrix can now be diagonalized: $ \begin{bmatrix}3 & -4\\4 & 3\end{bmatrix}$=$ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\-i & i\end{bmatrix}$$ \begin{bmatrix}3+4i & 0\\0 & 3-4i\end{bmatrix}$$ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\-i & i\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$. I found$ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\-i & i\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$=$\frac{1}{2i} \begin{bmatrix}i & -1\\i & 1\end{bmatrix}$ which is $ \begin{bmatrix}0.5 & 0.5i\\0.5 & -0.5i\end{bmatrix}$. It's easy to find out that the square roots of $3+4i$ are $2+i,-2-i$, and of $3-4i$ are $2-i,-2+i$. So now I would arrive at my 4 solutions:$$ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\-i & i\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}2+i & 0\\0 & 2-i\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0.5 & 0.5i\\0.5 & -0.5i\end{bmatrix}$$
$$ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\-i & i\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}2+i & 0\\0 & -2+i\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0.5 & 0.5i\\0.5 & -0.5i\end{bmatrix}$$
$$ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\-i & i\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-2-i & 0\\0 & 2-i\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0.5 & 0.5i\\0.5 & -0.5i\end{bmatrix}$$
$$ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\-i & i\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-2-i & 0\\0 & -2+i\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}0.5 & 0.5i\\0.5 & -0.5i\end{bmatrix}$$
When I work out my first candidate, I get a matrix, but when squared it doesn't give me $ \begin{bmatrix}3 & -4\\4 & 3\end{bmatrix}$ and so something isn't right. I don't know what I did wrong and ANY help from the math community is greatly appreciated. I feel that my line of thinking is correct, where did I go wrong? And does anyone happen to know online software that can do matrix multiplications with complex entries, because the TI doesn't work

Comment: With [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B-i%2Ci%7D%7D+times+%7B%7B2%2Bi%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C2-i%7D%7D+times+%7B%7B1%2F2%2Ci%2F2%7D%2C%7B1%2F2%2C-i%2F2%7D%7D), I got $\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$ for your first candidate

Comment: Yes, but did Wolfram also gives its opposite solution? The point is, when the (distinct!) eigenvalues get square rooted, through Diagonalization, there are for matrices D that you will obtain in the $PDP^{-1}$ process. I have done a ton of those where eigenvalues are distinct and real, because then the algebra is very straight forward. I want to know where it breaks down in my work in my post, because from a pure mathematical standpoint, my set up ought to work

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B-i%2Ci%7D%7D+times+%7B%7B-2-i%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C-2%2Bi%7D%7D+times+%7B%7B1%2F2%2Ci%2F2%7D%2C%7B1%2F2%2C-i%2F2%7D%7D) gives $\begin{bmatrix}-2&1\\-1&-2\end{bmatrix}$ for your fourth candidate

Comment: Can Wolfram alpha do matrix multiplications with complex entries? That way I can check my work and that would be so helpful...

Comment: Yes it can; click on the Wolfram Alpha links in my answer or comments above to see examples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A = [\begin{smallmatrix}3 & -4\\4 & 3\end{smallmatrix}]$ and $\chi_A(\lambda)$ be its characteristic polynomial. Since
$$\chi_{A}(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I_2 - A) = \lambda^2 - 6\lambda + 25$$
By [Cayley Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), we have
$$A^2 - 6A + 25 I_2 = 0
\iff (A+5I_2)^2 = 16 A \iff (A - 5I_2)^2 = -4A
$$
Taking "square root" on both sides and rearrange, one find $A$ has following four square roots.
$$\pm \frac14(A + 5I_2) = \pm \begin{bmatrix}2 & - 1\\1 & 2\end{bmatrix},\quad \pm \frac{i}{2}(A - 5 I_2) = \pm i\begin{bmatrix}-1 & -2\\2 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: That's a very interesting approach. Never thought about CH theorem even though I am aware of this theorem. This is great because it seems like the amount of algebra is less, something else to ponder about...

Comment: I played around with your method with a couple of "made up" problems. This method is considerably faster than the method through Diagonalization. No hastle with finding eigenvalues (it sucks when they contain radicals)  and corresponding eigenvectors. Thanks for sharing. I learned something today!

Answer (score 1):

Your work seems correct.  Doing the matrix multiplications for your four candidates

in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B-i%2Ci%7D%7D+times+%7B%7B-2-i%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C-2%2Bi%7D%7D+times+%7B%7B1%2F2%2Ci%2F2%7D%2C%7B1%2F2%2C-i%2F2%7D%7D) gives these square roots:  $\pm\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\pm\begin{bmatrix}i&2i\\-2i&i\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Then I must be doing something silly when working out my candidates. I need to check this out again. And after playing with W.A, it can take complex entries, which is GREAT!. Thanks...something to play with now because now I can go through my paper work step...by...step to see where my silly mistake is

Answer (score 0):

There should only be two square root matrices.  $\pm\begin{bmatrix} 2&-1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$

I have been noodling with this a bit.

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & -i\\i & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2&-1\\1&2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} i&2i\\-2i&i\end{bmatrix}$

Appears to work, and so would

$-\begin{bmatrix} i&2i\\-2i&i\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Why? A 2 by 2 matrix can have 4 roots. I have plenty of examples...A very simple example is the 4 roots of the unit matrix 1,0 on the first row and 0,1 on the second row. Square rooting gives 4 answers, being the rows 1,0 with 0,1 and then -1,0 with 0,-1 and then we also have 0,1 with 1,0 and then 0,-1 with -1,0. FOUR answers

Comment: Sorry, there are two matrices with real entries.

Comment: Doug, how do you know that? I am looking for an (algebraic) mistake in my work. I am expecting 4 answers, even if the other 2 have complex entries. If it works for real eigenvalues of the matrix to be squarerooted, why not for this particular case?

Comment: As you say, @imranfat, there are $2\times 2$ matrices with four square roots. But your particular matrix only has two square roots. I don't know why $-$ perhaps you can shed some light on this, Doug?

Comment: @TonyK Then what is wrong with my proposed solutions? Because this is exactly the same way how it works for real solutions. Each eigenvalue has two square roots and there are two eigenvalues, so this gives 4 options (basic combinatorics)